# Javascript and PHP file upload app redirects and causes download prompt

Tags: javascript, php

I have a file upload application that uses ajax to call a upload.php file in order to upload multiple files. The javascript also shows a progress bar and enables drag and drop feature for page.

The problem is that when files are dragged and dropped the application causes the download window to appear prompting me to download the files to my local machine. The intent is to upload not download. I don't know what is causing this. Also, the application redirects the user to the upload.php page where an array of processsed files are displayed to the user. I want the user to stay on the page that they uploaded the files from so they can see the files that were uploaded. I have a "Processed files" div tag that shows the processed files. Commenting the echo statement does not work.

Below is all the main code I am using that performs all the upload functionality. Thank you.

// upload.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$allowed = ['zip', '7z', 'txt', 'pdf', 'mp4', 'png', 'jpg', 'zip'];
$processed = [];

foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key => $name) {
    if($_FILES['files']['error'][$key] === 0) {

        $temp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];

        $ext = explode('.', $name);
        $ext = strtolower(end($ext));

        $file = $name;

        if(in_array($ext, $allowed) && move_uploaded_file($temp, 'uploads/' . $file)) {
            $processed[] = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'file' => $file,
                'uploaded' => true
            );
        } else {
            $processed[] = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'uploaded' => false
            );
        }

    }
}

//echo json_encode($processed);
```

// upload.js

```
var app = app || {};

(function(o) {
    "use strict";

// Private methods
var ajax, getFormData, setProgress;

ajax = function(data) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var uploaded;

    xmlhttp.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        if(this.readyState === 4) {
            if(this.status === 200) {

                uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response);

                if(typeof o.options.finished === 'function') {
                    o.options.finished(uploaded);
                }

            } else {
                if(typeof o.options.error === 'function') {
                    o.options.error();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
        var percent;

        if(e.lengthComputable === true) {
            percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            setProgress(percent);
        }
    });

    xmlhttp.open('post', o.options.processor);
    xmlhttp.send(data);

};

getFormData = function(source) {
    var data = new FormData();
    var i;

    for(i = 0; i < source.length; i = i + 1) {
        data.append('files[]', source[i]);
    }

    return data;
};

setProgress = function(value) {
    if(o.options.progressBar !== undefined) {
        o.options.progressBar.style.width = value ? value + '%' : 0;
    }

    if(o.options.progressText !== undefined) {
        o.options.progressText.textContent = value ? value + '%' : '';
    }
};

o.uploader = function(options) {
    o.options = options;

    if(o.options.files !== undefined) {
        ajax(getFormData(o.options.files));
    }
};

}(app));
```

// global.js

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');
    var barFill = document.getElementById('bar-fill');
    var barFillText = document.getElementById('bar-fill-text');
    var uploadsFinished = document.getElementById('uploads-finished');

    var startUpload = function(files) {
        app.uploader({
            files: files,
            progressBar: barFill,
            progressText: barFillText,
            processor: 'upload.php',

            finished: function(data) {
                var x;
                var uploadedElement;
                var uploadedAnchor;
                var uploadedStatus;
                var currFile;

                for(x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1) {
                    currFile = data[x];

                    uploadedElement = document.createElement('div');
                    uploadedElement.className = 'upload-console-upload';

                    uploadedAnchor = document.createElement('a');
                    uploadedAnchor.textContent = currFile.name;

                    if(currFile.uploaded) {
                        uploadedAnchor.href = 'uploads/' + currFile.file;
                    }

                    uploadedStatus = document.createElement('span');
                    uploadedStatus.textContent = currFile.uploaded ? 'Uploaded' : 'Failed';

                    uploadedElement.appendChild(uploadedAnchor);
                    uploadedElement.appendChild(uploadedStatus);

                    uploadsFinished.appendChild(uploadedElement);
                }

                uploadsFinished.className = '';

            },

            error: function() {
                console.log('There was an error');
            }
        });
    };

    // Standard form upload
    document.getElementById('standard-upload').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var standardUploadFiles = document.getElementById('standard-upload-files').files;
        e.preventDefault();

        startUpload(standardUploadFiles);
    });

    // Drop functionality
    dropZone.ondrop = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.className = 'upload-console-drop';

        startUpload(e.dataTransfer.files);
    };

    dropZone.ondragover = function() {
        this.className = 'upload-console-drop drop';
        return false;
    };

    dropZone.ondragleave = function() {
        this.className = 'upload-console-drop';
        return false;
    };
}());
```

Comment: _“Also, the application redirects the user to the upload.php”_ - I don’t see anything in the code that would make this even _technically_ possible (you can not redirect the front end from the response to a background request, so any such “redirect” would have to be explicitly performed using JavaScript) … This rather sounds as if your form was maybe submitting normally, due to some script error that prevents the JS from interfering as intended. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There is no error reported in console when selecting a file using the form button. However, when dragging and dropping file I get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexptected end of JSON input' referreing to 'uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response);' But, the app prompts the user to download as it performs the upload.

Comment: Go check what that response actually was (network panel), it sounds like something went wrong on the server side.